# Rails - menu for users

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app I render a list of all users.

```
@vk.friends do |friend|
    = friend.username
    = friend.sex
    = friend.birth_date
```

How can I make a menu of links which show male and female users (`friend.sex == 1` for females or `friend.sex == 2` for males)? Should I use some javascript or just `render`. Maybe you can suggest any jquery plugins.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the very nice gem `has_scope`: https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope

Very easy to use, for example, let's say the FriendsController:

```
class FriendsController < ApplicationController

  has_scope :sex, default: 'all' do |controller, scope, value|
    if value == 'all'
      scope.scoped
    else
      scope
    end
  end

  def index
    @friends = apply_scopes(@vk.friends).all
  end

# in index view:
= form_tag action: :index do
  - options = [ ['All', 'all'], ['Male', 1], ['Female', 2] ]
  = select_tag(:sex, options_for_select(options, params[:sex]))
  = submit_tag
```